# interfacing with hadoop services in c++

Tags: c++, hadoop

From a c++ application, what are the best ways to connect to various service components of hadoop, like namenode, datanodes, jobtracker etc., so that its configuration can be changed or monitored. 
Is it that one need to create JVMs for each of these components to interact with them from c++ application or the web interfaces these component provide, allow configuration of parameters dynamically for example changing the replication factor, updating xml files, reporting status of job etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should checkout

[Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/streaming.html).
[Hadoop-C++](https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-stream-mapreduce/)

Hadoop Streaming basically provides an interface to hadoop for any language which can input from `stdin` and output to `stdout`.

Comment: Hi Manoj, thanks for the answer. But as far as I understood, hadoop streaming could allow c++ application to run as mapReduce job, but I need something else. My c++ application need to interact with hadoop components for some configuration related params...

Comment: Ok then this will be useful: 

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/

Comment: You can write quick C++ routines using libcurl to get XML or text data. None of them are POST http requests so I am sure you cannot update a configuration but you can fetch many of them.